# Are both versions correct?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

*source*: AT THE BACK OF THE NORTH WIND | GEORGE MACDONALD

> 1. But for a four-wheeler **as** takes families and their **luggages**, he's the very horse.

I was searching for the usage of *luggages* and found the above sentence. I don't understand what it means.

I found another version, as below, which is more comprehensible to me.

> 2. But for a four- wheeler **that** takes families and their **luggage**, he's the very horse.

Are both versions correct?

Comment: Keep in mind that 1871 wasn't yesterday.

Comment: When you found these quotations, did they not give a publication date?  If you search the title, don’t you get some clues?

Comment: @Xanne the intention of your response?

Comment: I’m suggesting that a little research will tell you a lot, and what you find out should be included in your question.

Comment: From what I remember from reading the book many years ago, (1) is a representation of the speech of a Victorian cab driver. I don't know where you got (2) from, but it's obviously the same speech rendered into standard English.

Comment: A second version, “simplified for children,” was published in 1914, which is probably the source of the quotation in standard English. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_the_Back_of_the_North_Wind. Luggage is usually a non-count noun.

Comment: It's an old-fashioned relativiser usage. We'd use 'that' or 'which' now.